# Custom AuthorizeAttribute cached from previous request

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc

Consider a controller method:

```
EmployeeDetail(int userId)
```

The controller method is used for both editing an existing employee (userId!=0) and adding a new employee (userId==0).

Securing this method, with have an attribute derived from AuthorizationAttribute.  In this attribute we check for authorization in the OnAuthorization override.

That said we're noticing some caching that we were not expecting.  If we hit EmployeeDetail?userID=0 and then make a subsequent request to EmployeeDetail?userID=9999, we can see during OnAuthorization that it is the same instance of the CustomAuthorizationAttribute class that was loaded in the previous request.  It's GetHashCode is the same and we can see that a property that was set in the previous call is still set for the subsequent call.

**Is it normal for AuthorizationAttribute instances to be reused/cached over multiple http requests to the controller?**

Answer (score 0):

I do not have a definitive answer, but as I dig thru the code I would guess that the attributes, and more specifically their related type descriptor, are cached:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.typedescriptor.refresh?view=net-5.0

I think the issue here is that properties, in the context of an attribute, are considered named parameters.  Given that these parameters are set at compile time, they should be the same and caching should be fine.  But beware of using properties for any work storage.